# Woocommerce autofocus on input fields "billing_first_name"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have custom checkout page. First I'm showing content with added to cart items and than using this action to show billing form

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' ); ?>
```

Page scrolls down because of the autofocus on first name field.

Tried to use filters like this one

```
 add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields','disable_autofocus_billing_firstname');
     function disable_autofocus_billing_firstname($fields) {
        $fields['billing_first_name']['autofocus'] = false;
        return $fields;
      }
```

Also tried to blur the field with jQuery and vanila JS no effect. Is there is some updates for Woo that I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it'd be easier to use JS .focus() function?

Comment: unfortunately, wordpress overrides JS

Answer (score 0):

For overriding core fields need to use the hook 'woocommerce_checkout_fields'

You need to use the snippet below in order to disable the autofocus on checkout field:

```php
/* Disable autofocus at checkout */
function custom_checkout_disable_autofocus_firstname( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['autofocus'] = false;

    return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_checkout_disable_autofocus_firstname' );
```

Comment: I have added thi code to functions.php and no effect, also tried to add to the bottom of checkout.php and no effect, too

Comment: @ultrapanam Could you try to use this filter with low priority for late execution? For example, add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_checkout_disable_autofocus_firstname', 999);

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately.